# no operator ">" matches these operands

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble with this program I am writing. I believe that I need to overload the > operator but I am not sure how to do so. Can someone shed some light on this for me?

My code so far (incomplete):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //Includes the file stream for inputting and outputting files.
#include <string> //Fixes the error i get with some operands.
#include <iomanip> //Helps with report formatting.

using namespace std;

void sort(record A[], int size, int sortField);

struct record
{
string CustId, SPID, CustLN, CustFN;
int Q1;
double P1;
int Q2;
double P2;
int Q3;
double P3;
string LOD;
bool ShipRec;
string NCD, PreMethod;
double TotalSales;
};

int main()
{
ifstream InFile("master.txt");
ofstream OutFile1("report1.txt");
ofstream OutFile2("report2.txt");
ofstream OutFile3("report3.txt");
ofstream OutFile11("report11.txt");
ofstream OutFile13("report13.txt");
ofstream OutFile15("report15.txt");

record Customer[100];
while (!InFile.eof())
{
    int i = 0;

    InFile >> Customer[i].CustId >> Customer[i].SPID >> Customer[i].CustLN >>     Customer[i].CustFN >> Customer[i].Q1 >> Customer[i].P1 >> Customer[i].Q2 >> Customer[i].P2 >> Customer[i].Q3 >> Customer[i].P3 >> Customer[i].LOD >> Customer[i].ShipRec >> Customer[i].NCD >> Customer[i].PreMethod;

    Customer[i].TotalSales = (Customer[i].Q1 * Customer[i].P1) + (Customer[i].Q2 * Customer[i].P2) + (Customer[i].Q3 * Customer[i].P3);


}


}

void sort(record A[], int size, int sortField)
{
if (sortField = 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
            {
                record temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

else if (sortField = 2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
            {
                record temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

else if (sortField = 3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
            {
                record temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

else if (sortField = 11)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
            {
                record temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

else if (sortField = 13)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
            {
                record temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

else if (sortField = 15)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
            {
                record temp = A[j];
                A[j] = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I get this error in my sort function, in the if statement, when A[j] is compared to A[j+1].

Comment: It'd be hard to advise how to write your comparison function unless you tell us what exactly the comparison criteria is.

Comment: What are you comparing, which data member?

Comment: Consider replacing your '=' in your 'if' and 'else if' statements by '=='. Right now it's like you were trying to assign a vlue instead of verifying if it equals to something.

Comment: a great place to find the C++ definition of all of the basic operators in a handy table is located here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_operators.  This table also defines the standand signature of the operators w/proper use of const.  bool operator>(const record& rhs) const;  is the standard signature to provide the operator> in the struct record.  C++ does provide any of the six logical operators by default for structs or classes. So in any class you author, you have to write your own logical operators as needed by your code.

Answer (score 1):

The sort field is an argument to your function, so you can't write a regular `operator<`, because it won't be able to see the value of that argument.  (Unless you make it global. Don't do that).

Assuming there isn't a special reason why you have to write your own *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm, the simplest solution is:

```
class SortByField {
  int sortField_;
public:
  explicit SortByField(int f) : sortField_(f) {}
  // default copy ctor is fine
  bool operator() (record const &a, record const &b) const;
};

void sort(record A[], int size, int sortField) {
  std::sort(A, A+size, SortByField(sortField));
}
```

now, all that remains is to write that function call operator. I'm guessing it should look something like this:

```
bool SortByField::operator() (record const &a, record const &b) const {
  switch (sortField_) {
  case 1: return a.CustID < b.CustID;
  case 2: return a.SPID < b.SPID;
  // ...
  default: return false; // maybe we should check sortField is valid before this?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `sortField` chooses which field to compare. If that's the case you should change your code to:

```
if (sortField == 1) // <-- use '==' for comparisson
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < size-1; j++) // <-- should probably be size-1
    {
      if (A[j].CustId > A[j + 1].CustId) // <-- test the sortField
      {
        record temp = A[j];
        A[j] = A[j + 1];
        A[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and similarly for other `sortField` values